# Bypassing website using hCaptch + Cloud Flare protection

Tags: python, web-scraping, captcha, cloudflare, 2captcha

Does anyone have any idea about how to bypass hCaptcha on cloud flare protected websites?
I have searched everywhere but couldn't find any solutions (actually if there is a way, cloud flare employees should get fired).

PS: my problem is that cloud flare doesn't redirect me to website after solving the captcha even myself. I know the problem is with browser checking but I'm using `undetected_chromedriver` with *user-data-dir* argument to normalize the automation.

***code snippet:***

```
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
```

```
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={path_to_data_dir}')
options.add_argument(f'--profile-directory=Profile 1')
```

Comment: I would be glad if you can share your experience :)